# Defining a main caption for two sub figures

Tags: beamer, captions

```
\subsection{frame 4}
\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.6\textwidth}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{image/A.png}
\caption{A}
\end{figure}
\column{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{image/B.png}
\caption{B}
\end{figure}
\end{columns}
\caption{Main caption}
\end{frame}
```

Adding \caption{Main caption}, in the second last line, displays error. Can someone alternative ways of defining a main caption?

Comment: Hello, you actually don't have two subfigures, but two figures. The last `caption` cannot be related to a figure since it is not inside of a `figure` environment.

Comment: Please have a look at [TeX.SX starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) and [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to see how to improve your post so people can help you

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix: use `\captionof` from the `caption` package

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\subsection{frame 4}
\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.6\textwidth}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A}
\end{figure}
\column{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{B}
\end{figure}
\end{columns}
\captionof{figure}{Main caption}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Clean way: Have a look at the `subcaption` package

Comment: This works, but the problem is the two figures have been labeled as figure 1 and figure 2.Adding `\captionof{figure}{Main caption}` creates a new label Figure 3. How can I avoid this?

Comment: @Natasha Per default there are no numbers shown in beamer. Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows your problem.

Comment: I have included `\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]`.